# How validate "(344) 004-1585" type of phone number

Tags: php, phone-number

I mask the phone numbers like "(342) 004-1452" with jQuery. Now I am trying validate this input with PHP. I tried

```
if(!preg_match('\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}', $_POST['tel']))
{
    $errors['tel']='enter a valid phone number';
}
```

But I think my preg_match expression is not valid. What is the right preg_match expression to validate this data?

Comment: @hd1 I think you wrote the URL of the post incorrectly it says page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing delimiters. Wrap it with `/`:

```
'/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/'
```

If you've configured your environment to display warnings, you *should* be seeing one:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

If you haven't turned on warnings, or have intentionally turned them off, you should stop developing PHP code until you turn them back on.

Answer (score 2):

You're all over-thinking it. All you truly need to do is verify that the given string contains the proper number of numeric characters.

```
$input = '(342) 004-1452';
$stripped = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);

if( strlen($stripped) != 10 ) {
    printf('%s is not a valid phone number.', $input);
} else {
    printf('%s is a valid phone number. yay.', $input);
}

//output: (342) 004-1452 is a valid phone number. yay.
```

You can pretty-fy the phone number back from whatever garbled input someone has fed it with:

```
$phone_pretty = sprintf('(%s) %s-%s',
    substr($stripped,0,3),
    substr($stripped,3,3),
    substr($stripped,6,4)
    );
```

Comment: Because `)(*@#$(@123456$^33$38` will be valid in this example, which I'm assuming He's not going for.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst the only "valid format" of a phone number is "X digits", 10 if you're in north america. Given some of the truly ass-backwards ways people record phone numbers, and the complete inability of people to follow instructions [like me and this answer!] the only way to take a phone number from a user [in a single input field] is to reduce it to digits like I've done. I don't care if they write a homicidal rant in the phone number box, if it has 10 digits in it I'm going to assume that those comprise a telephone number.

Comment: I completely understand you, but for the context of his question, he was asking for validating `(000) 000-000` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression looks okay, but `preg_match()` needs you to supply delimiters for the start and end of the regular expression within the quotes.

These markers are typically slashes, but can actually be a number of other characters.

So adding slashes to your line of code gives the following:

```
if(!preg_match('/\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}/', $_POST['tel']))
```

If you want the string to be only a phone number and nothing else, you may also want to limit the regex by adding `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end:

```
if(!preg_match('/^\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$/', $_POST['tel']))
```

Hope that helps.

(that said, I would add that the phone number format you're checking only applies for US and countries in the US dialling plan; most international countries use different formats, so if you want to accept international visitors, you'll need a much looser regex than this)